# how to draw lines per each intensity along days for survivors?

Tags: r, graph, dataframe

I was wondering if somebody could help me with a data set, I would like to make a graph of survivors on the y-axis and day on the x-axis. The problem I am having is trying to break up the data by the four intensity groups. Optimally I would like a graph with a trend line for all four intensities so that I can see if there are significant differences between them. Any help or tips would be much appreciated!Here is what my data frame looks like:

```
  Intensity Day Survivors
1        0.0   0        37
2        0.0   1        29
3        0.0   2         9
4        0.0   3         1
5        0.0   4         1
6        0.0   5         0
7        0.0   6         0
8        0.0   7         0
9        0.1   0        40
10       0.1   1        28
11       0.1   2         8
12       0.1   3         0
13       0.1   4         0
14       0.1   5         0
15       0.1   6         0
16       0.1   7         0
17       0.2   0        40
18       0.2   1        26
19       0.2   2        15
20       0.2   3         8
21       0.2   4         5
22       0.2   5         3
23       0.2   6         1
24       0.2   7         0
25       0.4   0        47
26       0.4   1        29
27       0.4   2         5
28       0.4   3         0
29       0.4   4         0
30       0.4   5         0
31       0.4   6         0
32       0.4   7         0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(x, aes(x = Day, y = Survivors, colour = as.factor(Intensity))) + 
   geom_point(pch = 15) +
   geom_line() +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Lattice also does this easily.

```
library(lattice)

xyplot(Survivors ~ Day,
       data=x,
       groups=Intensity,
       grid=TRUE,
       type=c('p','l'),
       auto.key=list(title='Intensity', space='right')
       )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel, just take a scatter plot with smooth lines and markers, then add 4 data series corresponding to your intensities
[image: 1 minute work]

Then add whatever legend/descriptions you want

Comment: A solution in R was requested.  You might want to delete this answer.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - I don't see the user explicitly requesting a solution in R. The only indication is the tag, which might be because he came up with that data in R after analysis