# Create a scatter plot of a continuous variable grouped by categorical variables

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, ggplot2

I have categorical variable called year, I want to plot for each individual (category), the risk value(continuous).  I want the risk to be connected by lines between each year.  If I simply plot risk on the Y axis and then color code the variable it is a mess because many individuals have the same value or something very similar and you can't see each individual's changing risk through time. Ive included an image of how I think it should look like that I created in Excel (the names/years may not match).  I am creating a new "series" for each individual, the problem is I have >200 individuals so don't want to sit here and do this for each one.
[image: Excelplot]

Here is a sample of the data I am working with:

```
structure(list(IDr = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("F07001_f", 
"F07001_fc", "F07002_f", "F07002_fc", "F07003_fc", "F07004_f", 
"F07005_f", "F07005_fc", "F07006_f", "F07006_fc", "F07008_f", 
"F07009_f", "F07009_fc", "F07010_f", "F07010_fc", "F07011_f", 
"F07011_fc", "F07014_f", "F07014_fc", "F07015_fc", "F07017_fc", 
"F07018_fc", "F07019_f", "F07019_fc", "F07020_f", "F07020_fc", 
"F07021_fc", "F07022_f", "F07023_f", "F07024_fc", "F10001_fc", 
"F10004_fc", "F10008_fc", "F10009_f", "F10009_fc", "F10010_f", 
"F10012_fc", "F10013_fc", "F98015_f", "M07007_m", "M07012_m", 
"M07013_m", "M07016_m", "M10007_m", "M10011_m", "M10015_m"), class = "factor"), 
    ln1wr = c(0.833126490613386, 0.824526258616325, 0.990730077688989, 
    0.981816265754353, 0.933462450382474, 0.932242818088082, 
    0.833865187498825, 0.859381698700969, 0.821716281354653, 
    0.861496579787016, 0.746687947487975, 0.755605414399556, 
    0.689741387425112, 0.694046775802782, 0.746403546860377, 
    0.765095679872529, 1.05733880335233, 1.04549276633745, 0.925765702236673, 
    0.909990929725627), MooseYear = c(2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 
    2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 7.08, 7.08, 8.09, 8.09, 
    9.1, 9.1, 10.11, 10.11, 2007, 2007)), .Names = c("IDr", "ln1wr", 
"MooseYear"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I don't really know where to start, it seems simple enough, but i can't even get a plot command to work without it turning the plot into a bargraph.  Ive tried

```
plot(ln1wr~ID, data=test)
plot(ln1wr~MooseYear, data=test)
scatterplot(ln1wr~MooseYear, data=test)
```

None of them even begin to come close to a starting point.  I don't care if it plots each individual on the x or y axis, or bins each individual.  I just need to see how risk is changing through time for each individual and look at the changing slope between points.  You will notice that there are multiple measures for 1 individual within that year.  I have an additional classification I could incorporate (season) Im working on dealing with that.  I just am hoping it will average out or wash out in the end.

Comment: @Didzis MooseYear is a categorical variable, so technically 07.08 is meant to indicate winter of 2007/2008. In the sample data I did not convert it to a factor. Apologize for that.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708458/how-to-draw-lines-per-each-intensity-along-days-for-survivors/13720227#13720227

Comment: I think you should clean your data (MooseYear)

Comment: This is very easy to do in ggplot once the data are in the right format. Your data, however, isn't. In particular, there are multiple values of `ln1wr` for each `IDr`-`MooseYear` combination. Is it possible these multiple observations are, in fact, observations at different dates/times within the year? It would probably help if you posted some of the original data and code that the data you posted above is derived from.

Comment: @RoyalTS This is original data.  Yes, the multiple points are because the data represents 2 up to 4 measures per year.  The additional descriptors are season, if there is a calf present or if its day/night.  I was hoping I wouldn't have to include those variables. However, it seems I would have to?  How would that make it easier in ggplot?

Comment: @Kerry This isn't so much a `ggplot` question then. It's more a question about what you want the graph to look like. If you have between two and four observations per year, how many observations per year do you want to display in the graph? If it's less then four I suppose you'd want to do some averaging. If it's more than two, how do you want to handle those dates for which some observations don't have any data? Break the lines? linearly interpolate between them?

Comment: @RoyalTS If there are missing observations, I would expect a break.  As there are missing points for some years/seasons etc.  I wasn't sure if or how the graphical program could handle multiple data for the same year.  At this moment, i would guess to average them before plotting, then if I needed I could make a separate plot for each subdivision (eg season calf time).  Just need a place to get started

Comment: You could create a new column that uses information from MooseYear and your season column. Depending on the coding for season, 2009.00 would be winter (aka 08.09), 2009.25 might be spring, 2009.50 summer, and 2009.75 fall. That might remove some (or many) of your overlapping observations. Also is F07001_fc different from F07001_f? On your example graph the ID's are truncated at the underscor.

Comment: @dcarlson no the ID is correct.  Individual F07001 went from having a calf (fc) to having no calf(f) or vice versa.  In my Excel example I did not include reproductive status.  Either way for discussion only I would consider F07001_f different individual from F07001_fc.